# PromQL for Monitoring Kubernetes Replicas

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Every rolling update occur, the pod name of deployment must be changed. I have deployment that has 3 replicas and I want to monitor of each replica. If the pod name always change, what should I do to monitor each of replica?

**Example current promQL for pod's memory monitoring:**

**request resource**

```
kube_pod_container_resource_requests{namespace="default",container="my-container",resource="memory"}
```

**limit resource**

```
kube_pod_container_resource_limits{namespace="default",container="my-container",resource="memory"}
```

**current memory usage**

```
sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{namespace="default",container!="POD",container!="",pod!="",container="my-container"}) by (container)
```

I appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use any [aggregate function](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/basics/timeseries/#aggregating-time-series) to be independent from the label "pod".

Example:

- Series 1: "pod":"pod-1", "replica":"replica-1", "namespace":"dev"
- Series 2: "pod":"pod-1", "replica":"replica-2", "namespace":"dev"
- Series 3: "pod":"pod-2", "replica":"replica-1", "namespace":"dev"
- Series 4: "pod":"pod-2", "replica":"replica-2", "namespace":"dev"

sum by(replica) (metric) will aggregate Series 1 with 3 and Series 2 with 4.

sum by(pod) (metric) will aggregate Series 1 with 2 and Series 3 with 4.

sum by(namespace) (metric) will aggregate all 4 Series.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your suggestion. For deployment replicas, let say I have 3 replicas with 500MiB memory limit of each pod. Is summarize the all load and limit makes equal calculation the way monitor each pod? example (W/ summarize, limit will be 1,5GiB and load 600 is equal to each pod with 500MiB limit and 200 load)?

Comment: If you aggregat two series into one series, there will be less information, that is the nature of aggregation. But with some metrics it can really be what you want. I'd rather not aggregate resource_limits and resource_requests but it might be useful to aggregate with max, if you put them into relation: max by(...) (resource_requests)/max by(...) (resource_limits). Aggregation is extremely useful in cases where your infrastructure adds labels that lead to additional timelines.